# Getting offset_ptr of object in shared memory

Tags: boost, shared-memory

How can i access the offset_ptr of the object which is created in the shared memory?

```
segment = new managed_shared_memory(create_only, "MySharedMemory", segmentSize);  
line = segment->construct<Line>("Line1")("line");
```

I want to access of offset_ptr for Line object..

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to declare the offset pointer with your Line type:

```
boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<Line> offset_p;
```

Second, you assign it:

```
offset_p = line;
```

Now, offset_p holds an offset from from line to itself, so you can get a pointer to *line* and use it in any process like this:

```
draw_line( offset_p.get() );
```